# Get ISO's mounted and change device type to client

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, iso, powercli

I'm trying to find a way with PowerCLI to get a list of ISO's that are mounted in VM's and change the device type to "client device." Originally I thought that using the get-datastore would work to find the ISO's, however I was struggling to find ISO's, and ran into this line of code while doing some searching:

```
(Get-VM | Get-View | Where {$_.Runtime.ToolsInstallerMounted}) | % {$_.Name}
```

I tried this, however I didn't get a list of ISO's mounted. Was wondering if anyone here might know how to get a list of ISO's mounted on VM's and change the device type to client through scripting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, remove WhatIf to remove the ISO:

```
Get-VM | 
Get-CDDRive | 
Where-Object {$_.IsoPath} | 
Set-CDDrive -NoMedia -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

Comment: I tested with the -whatif, but had a question for you Shay: is this only removing all the mounted ISO's in any VM's that I have or is this also switching the device type on VM's to client Device? With whatif it doesn't specify if it is also making the device type to client.

Comment: @Julian The code finds all mounted ISO files (in all VMS) and sets the device type to 'client device' (no media).

Comment: Thanks Shay! One last question, if I just want to search for a specific ISO what would I do to alter the filter? (let's assume the name of this ISO is"NAME.iso". I'm trying the following however when I do this it isn't returning any results:

Comment: Get-VM | Get-CDDrive | Where-Object {$_.name -like "NAME.iso"} | Set-CDDrive -NoMedia -Confirm:$false -whatif

Comment: Replace $_.Name with $_.IsoPath and try again